# How to format time 12:00:00 or 12:00:am to 12:00 AM?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using strtotime() 
its working fine for $time = '12:00:00'; 
but

```
$time = '12:00:am'; 
echo date('h:i A ', strtotime($time));
```

it return 4:00 PM but I want output is 12:00 AM

Comment: ` '12:00:am'` is *not* a valid date format

Comment: The format "12:00:am" is not valid, as after the second colon a seconds number is expected.

Comment: but I have a lot of data in both formats what can I do? @ John Conde @Paul Stelian

Comment: first of all correct your format $time = '12:00:am'; to this $time = '12:00 am'; or $time = '12:00 AM';

Comment: You need the **date** component as well as the time for `strrotime()` so assuming the clock is *today* and assuming that you understand that 12 AM is **midnight** (not midday) : `date('Y-m-d H:i A', strtotime(  date('Y-m-d') . " " . str_replace(':00:am', ' AM', $time)  ));`

Comment: surely @CD001 you'd need another `str_replace` for the PM times...... or insert an array of `[0] = "AM", [1] = "PM" `

Comment: @Martin true but that wasn't specified, if I was going to give a proper answer I'd be using `DateTime` anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Function could help you. It takes a time like your format "12:00:00 or 12:00:am" and output it's as your needs like this "12:00 AM" .

```
function convert_time($the_time){
    $time_arr = explode(":",$the_time);
    if($time_arr[2] != "am" || $time_arr[2] != "pm"){
        if($time_arr[0] >= "0" && $time_arr[0] <= 12){
            if($time_arr[0] == 12 && $time_arr[1] > 00){
                $time_arr[2] = "pm";
            } else {
                $time_arr[2] = "am";
            }
        } else {
            $time_arr[2] = "pm";
        }
        $new_time = $time_arr[0].":".$time_arr[1]." ".strtoupper($time_arr[2]);
        return $new_time;
    }
    $new_time = $time_arr[0].":".$time_arr[1]." ".strtoupper($time_arr[2]);
    return $new_time;
}

$time = '12:00:am'; 
echo convert_time($time);
```

Comment: what does this function do?

Comment: this function takes a time like those 2 formats the users wands and convert it's to his needs. Did i miss something?